# How to get a nice output when calling jconsole?

Tags: j

I've recently started to learn J.
If find it useful when learning a new language to be able to quickly
map a bit of source code to an output and store it for later reference in Emacs org-mode.

But I'm having trouble with the cryptic `jconsole` when I want to do the evaluation.
For instance `jconsole --help` doesn't work.
And `man jconsole` brings up something about a Java tool. Same applies to googling.

I have for instance this bit of code from the tutorial saved in `temp.ijs`:

```
m =. i. 3 4
1 { m
23 23 23 23 (1}) m
```

Now when I run `jconsole < temp.ijs`, the output is:

```
      4 5 6 7
    0  1  2  3
23 23 23 23
 8  9 10 11
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to be:

```
 4 5 6 7

 0  1  2  3
23 23 23 23
 8  9 10 11
```

Again, ideally I'd like to have this without changing the source code at all,
i.e. just by passing some flag to `jconsole`.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well but I think it can't be done. What I usually do, is shebang the script with jconsole, put `echo`s where I need them and close with `exit''`. Call this with `jconsole temp.ijs`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This leads me to a temp solution: intersperse each source code line with `echo''`
and re-align the result of `jconsole < temp.ijs` which now becomes easier to parse.

Comment: Here's what little documentation JSoftware.com has on jconsole: http://www.jsoftware.com/user/install.htm

Comment: Looks depressing. I assumed things to be better since it's GPL now

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of J, where high-end mathematical functions known by a select few are amply documented (although one might need a PhD in mathematics to understand said documentation), and the base functions and utilities are documented sparsely.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently going with solving the problem on Emacs side, instead of on jconsole side.
I intersperse the source code with `echo''`:

```
(defun org-babel-expand-body:J (body params)
  "Expand BODY according to PARAMS, return the expanded body."
  (mapconcat #'identity (split-string body "\n") "\necho''\n"))
```

Execute it like this:

```
(j-strip-whitespace
 (org-babel-eval
  (format "jconsole < %s" tmp-script-file) ""))
```

And post-process assuming that only first row of each array is misaligned
(that has been my experience so far). Here's the result:

```
#+begin_src J
m =. i. 3 4
1 { m
23 23 23 23 (1}) m
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 4 5 6 7
: 
:  0  1  2  3
: 23 23 23 23
:  8  9 10 11
```

And here's the post-processing code:

```
(defun whitespacep (str)
  (string-match "^ *$" str))
(defun match-second-space (s)
  (and (string-match "^ *[^ ]+\\( \\)" s)
       (match-beginning 1)))
(defun strip-leading-ws (s)
  (and (string-match "^ *\\([^ ].*\\)" s)
       (match-string 1 s)))
(defun j-print-block (x)
  (if (= 1 (length x))
      (strip-leading-ws (car x))
    ;; assume only first row misaligned
    (let ((n1 (match-second-space (car x)))
      (n2 (match-second-space (cadr x))))
      (setcar
       x
       (if (and n1 n2)
       (substring (car x) (- n1 n2))
     (strip-leading-ws (car x))))
      (mapconcat #'identity x "\n"))))
(defun j-strip-whitespace (str)
  (let ((strs (split-string str "\n" t))
    out cur s)
    (while (setq s (pop strs))
      (if (whitespacep s)
      (progn (push (nreverse cur) out)
         (setq cur))
    (push s cur)))
    (mapconcat #'j-print-block
           (delq nil (nreverse out))
       "\n\n")))
```

Comment: I believe the misaligning you are seeing comes from J's three-space prompt for input lines (which is output after each command is accepted to prompt for more).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `echo` for explicit output, rather than rely on implicit output which is the case for the REPL function of `jconsole` normally.

Create the script, which I'm calling "tst2.js" below, and place the following code in it:

```
#!/Applications/j64/bin/jconsole
9!:7'+++++++++|-'
m =. i. 3 4
echo 1 { m
echo ''
echo 23 23 23 23 (1}) m
exit''
```

Of course, if your path to `jconsole` is different, then update the "shebang" line to be the actual path for your system.

Next, make sure the script is executable:

```
$ chmod +x tst2.js
```

or whatever you called your script.

Next, invoke it:

```
$ ./tst2.js
4 5 6 7

 0  1  2  3
23 23 23 23
 8  9 10 11
```

Note that the above output is identical to the output generated when you are in the interactive `jconsole`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with loose declarations. Every time you give the console a command, it replies with the answer. You should format your code in a verb and have it `echo` what you need.

```
foo =: 3 : 0
    m =. i. 3 4
    echo ''
    echo 1 { m
    echo ''
    echo 23 23 23 23 (1}) m
    ''
)
foo''
```

It can also be nameless and self executing if you're in a hurry:

```
3 : 0 ''
    m =. i. 3 4
    echo ''
    echo 1 { m
    echo ''
    echo 23 23 23 23 (1}) m
    ''
)
```

Comment: The code you give doesn't allow me to parse either visually or with code which
source code line produces which output (two outputs are merged).

Furthermore I cannot devise an automatic transformation
from code example in the question to your code, because it requires to make the decision
not to echo the first line.

Comment: I added blank lines. Unfortunately, it looks like the first line is always printed with a tab preceding it, so I opted to print an "empty" line first to standardize the output.

Comment: To do this automatically I need either `echo m =. i. 3 4`, i.e. echo on all lines, or echo on none.
Skipping echo on first line mean that I can somehow parse that it's a declaration (I can't).
On the other hand, adding echo to declaration produces output that jconsole wouldn't produce when
used interactively.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see what you're trying to do. You want to output some lines, but not others, arbitrarily. These added requirements aren't in your original question, which makes it particularly hard for me to guess what you are trying to accomplish. Declarations such as you have in your original posted code are "on the fly" commands sent to the console. If you want to have a standardized output, format your code in functions, echo what you need.

Comment: I want the output to look as if I had entered it into jconsole. The lines that jconsole echoes should be echoed, and ones that it doesn't, like `m =. i. 3 4` should not be echoed. Also I want a new line between each separate output to ease visual separation. You can see the desired result in my answer. But I'd prefer to do things on `jconsole` side and not with a bunch of fragile Emacs code.